Method not found: Void System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.set_Image(System.Drawing.Image) After assigning the icon in the SharpShell ToolStripMenuItem
I’m having trouble assigning an icon to a ToolStripMenuItem (context menu). As soon as I include mainItem.Image = image;, the DLL throws an exception. Without mainItem.Image = image;, everything is fine—the context menu is created and works perfectly. I created the DLL with SharpShell + .NET8 + Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility, following this guide.
text
The log was generated with this.
text
According to the log, the method is not found. Full log:
2024-08-31 10:03:49.113Z - explorer - SharpShell Diagnostics Initialised. Process explorer.
2024-08-31 10:03:49.132Z - explorer - SimpleContextMenu: Initializing shell extension...
2024-08-31 10:03:49.137Z - explorer - SimpleContextMenu: Shell extension initialised.
Parent folder: 
Items:
D:\Textdokument (neu) - Kopie - Kopie.mpr
2024-08-31 10:03:49.138Z - explorer - SimpleContextMenu: Query Context Menu for items:
D:\Textdokument (neu) - Kopie - Kopie.mpr
2024-08-31 10:03:49.140Z - explorer - error: SimpleContextMenu: An exception occured building the context menu.
2024-08-31 10:03:49.152Z - explorer - error: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.set_Image(System.Drawing.Image)'.
at SharpShell_DLL.SimpleContextMenu.CreateMenu()
at System.Lazy1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode) at System.Lazy1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
at SharpShell.SharpContextMenu.SharpContextMenu.SharpShell.Interop.IContextMenu.QueryContextMenu(IntPtr hMenu, UInt32 indexMenu, Int32 idCmdFirst, Int32 idCmdLast, CMF uFlags)
I am using Windows 11 22H2 + VS2022.
Code:
        protected override ContextMenuStrip CreateMenu()
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem mainItem; 
            ContextMenuStrip menu = new ContextMenuStrip();

            try
            {
                mainItem = new ToolStripMenuItem();
                image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\x\Documents\GitHub\Sauger_Automation\SharpShell_DLL\SharpShell_DLL\Resources\SG_16.ico");
                //image = Resource_SharpShell.SG_16.ToBitmap();
                //menuItem.Image = new Bitmap(Resource_SharpShell.SG_16.ToBitmap(), new Size(16, 16));
                //image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\x\Documents\GitHub\Sauger_Automation\SharpShell_DLL\SharpShell_DLL\Icons\SG_16.ico");
                //image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\x\Documents\GitHub\Sauger_Automation\SharpShell_DLL\SharpShell_DLL\Icons\SG_16.ico");
                mainItem.Image = image;
                mainItem.Text = name;
                menu.Items.Add(mainItem);

                mainItem.Click += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    var builder2 = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (var FulPath in SelectedItemPaths) { builder2.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}", Path.GetFullPath(FulPath))); }
                    RunWpfApp(SelectedItemPaths);
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                File.WriteAllLines("d:\\DEBUGssss.txt", new string[] { ex.Message });
            }

            return menu;
        }

Project.csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
        <EnableComHosting>true</EnableComHosting>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Remove="Icons\Icon Entry_71.ico" />
        <None Remove="Icons\SG_16.ico" />
        <None Remove="Icons\SG_16_Image.png" />
        <None Remove="Icons\SG_16_Image_JPG.jpg" />
        <None Remove="Icons\SG_64.ico" />
        <None Remove="Resources\Icon Entry_32.ico" />
        <None Remove="Resources\SG_16.ico" />
        <None Remove="Resources\SG_16_Image.png" />
        <None Remove="Resources\SG_16_Image_JPG.jpg" />
        <None Remove="Resources\SG_64.ico" />
        <None Remove="Resources\Wwop_48.ico" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <COMReference Include="{d37e2a3e-8545-3a39-9f4f-31827c9124ab}">
            <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
            <VersionMinor>4</VersionMinor>
            <VersionMajor>2</VersionMajor>
            <Guid>d37e2a3e-8545-3a39-9f4f-31827c9124ab</Guid>
        </COMReference>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" Version="8.0.8" />
        <PackageReference Include="SharpShell" Version="2.7.2" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Sauger_Automation\Sauger_Automation\Sauger_Automation.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Resource Include="Icons\Icon Entry_71.ico" />
        <Resource Include="Icons\SG_16.ico" />
        <Resource Include="Icons\SG_16_Image.png" />
        <Resource Include="Icons\SG_16_Image_JPG.jpg" />
        <Resource Include="Icons\SG_64.ico" />
        <Resource Include="Resources\Icon Entry_32.ico" />
        <Resource Include="Resources\SG_16_Image.png" />
        <Resource Include="Resources\SG_16_Image_JPG.jpg" />
        <Resource Include="Resources\SG_64.ico" />
        <Resource Include="Resources\Wwop_48.ico" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Resource Include="Resources\SG_16.ico">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Resource>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Update="Resource_SharpShell.Designer.cs">
            <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
            <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
            <DependentUpon>Resource_SharpShell.resx</DependentUpon>
        </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <EmbeddedResource Update="Resource_SharpShell.resx">
            <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
            <LastGenOutput>Resource_SharpShell.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
        </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>


Can someone please help me?
Thank you in advance.
Method not found: 'Void System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.set_Image(System.Drawing.Image)' After assigning the icon in the SharpShell ToolStripMenuItem

Have you thought about building a .NET Framework (4.8) library instead? No compatibility pack needed -- What added System.Drawing as a COM reference there?

Hi, I really want to use .NET8 with WPF. It works in general, but not with the icon.


tlbimp
4
2
d37e2a3e-8545-3a39-9f4f-31827c9124ab


